# Создание настроек приложения

Tags: android

Мне нужно сделать в приложении настройки (увеличение размера шрифта, и еще несколько возможностей.) Подскажите пожалуйста ресурс, где подробно на каком-то примере объясняется как это все реализовать.

Comment: офф.дока -
 https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html , от Климова -
 http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/preferences_framework.php , от Startandroid - http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/181-urok-111-android-3-fragments-preferencefragment-nastrojki-headers.html

Comment: Спасибо большое